# Was the singularity at the big bang a black hole?

Tags: cosmology, black-holes, spacetime, big-bang, singularities

Was the singularity at the big bang a black hole? If not, how does the singularity compare to a black hole?

Comment: Black hole singularities come from the solutions of general relativity, and in general describe very large masses which distort space and have a horizon after which nothing comes out and everything ends up on the singularity, the details depending on the metric used . If you read the duplicate answers you will see that the description in the previous sentence does not fit the universe, where galaxies and clusters of galaxies are receding from each other and  which  expansion is accelerating as seen in the images provided in the duplicate. I have included this in my answer in the duplicate

Comment: I don't quite get the "BB happening at a point" question as relating to this one:  I think it makes some possibly-questionable assumption as bearing on the type of cosmic inflation (based on scalar fields) which gained a lot of credibility from the 1980's thru the early 2000's.  The release of energy as the asymptotically-exponential expansion of space transitions to indefinite expansion tends to get identified with the BB, but I don't know if that identification is generally-accepted or otherwise valid.  It's unclear that that process occurs when inflation originates within BH's.

Comment: I doubt if I'd be making the above comment if inflaton particles or fields had been found, but I don't believe they have been, at least in the expected ranges for their mass.  I've also heard of some incompatibility with the CMB appearing.